# Prevent access to thank you page?

Tags: php, get, conditional-statements

I have a php form and I'm redirecting from:

```
http://wthdesign.net/contact.php
```

to this url:

```
http://wthdesign.net/contact.php?status=thanks
```

once my form is send:

but my problem is how do I prevent access to this url if the form was never sent in the first place?

Comment: what your needs ? say clearly friend...

Comment: Set the session just before redirecting and check whether it is set on the next page and unset it.

Comment: use some condition on checking the existence of POST variable on thanks page from contact.php

Comment: @Ankit OP redirects so there is no POST variable set. At least that is how I read it :-)

Comment: okay if you are redirecting then use either HTTP referrer or tokens in php

Comment: Actually, it's not harmful at all, you can leave it... WordPress does the same: www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=1&action=edit&message=1 `message=1` will show a success message even if you didn't modify anything.

Comment: @PeeHaa realized that so removed that wrong comment before your reply :)

Comment: @Ankit Ninja deletion FTW! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us the source code off contact.php

indeed SESSION is proberly the best way to go, and set the session like this.

```
if (mail(...)) {
  $_SESSION['allow_show_thanks'] = 1;
}
```

you have proberly some kind of switch case to handle status?

```
if (status == "thanks") {


} else {
  // show form
}
```

change that to

```
if (status == "thanks" && (isset($_SESSION['allow_show_thanks'] && $_SESSION['allow_show_thanks'] == 1) ) {
   // show thanks when status equals "thanks" AND SESSION['allow_show_thanks'] == 1

} else {
  // show form
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you just need to create session in the form and you need to check, whether the session was set with isset function. If not, use die at the beginning.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['thank'])) die;
```